# Material UI autocomplete with redux-form values getting destroyed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, redux-form

I'm trying to use Material UI's autocomplete component with redux wizard form

I was able to link the autocomplete provided by material UI but when i go back to previous page and come back to the second page where the autocomplete fields are, the field gets destroyed despite having destroyOnUnmount set to false. (All other fields doesn't get destroyed but only the fields in page 2 which uses material UI autocomplete feature) Actually I dont think it's getting destroyed because the value is still there you just can't see it in the input

Also When I click Submit, the Main Hobby section's value gets through but the multiple hobby section's value doesnt get through. Can anyone have a look and see what's wrong? Thanks

[image: Edit FORM VALUES]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define the value attribute of AutoComplete to show the selected values when you visit the form again.

You must note that the two fields in Hobby form need to be defined with different name

Also the onChange value of multi select AutoComplete need to inform reduxForm about the change

MultipleComplete.js

```
import React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Autocomplete } from "@material-ui/lab";
const hobbies = [
  { title: "WATCHING MOVIE" },
  { title: "SPORTS" },
  { title: "MUSIC" },
  { title: "DRAWING" }
];

const MultipleComplete = ({
  input,
  meta: { touched, error, submitFailed }
}) => {
  const { onChange, ...rest } = input;
  return (
    <div>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        limitTags={2}
        value={input.value || []}
        id="multiple-limit-tags"
        options={hobbies}
        onChange={(e, newValue) => {
          onChange(newValue);
        }}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.title === value.title}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            placeholder="Choose Multiple Hobbies"
            fullWidth
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default MultipleComplete;
```

AutoHobbyComplete.js

```
import React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Autocomplete } from "@material-ui/lab";
const hobbies = [
  { title: "WATCHING MOVIE" },
  { title: "SPORTS" },
  { title: "MUSIC" },
  { title: "DRAWING" }
];

const AutoHobbyComplete = ({
  input,
  meta: { touched, error, submitFailed }
}) => {
  const getSelectedOption = () => {
    return hobbies.find(o => o.title === input.value);
  };
  const { onChange, ...rest } = input;
  return (
    <div>
      <Autocomplete
        autoSelect
        value={getSelectedOption()}
        options={hobbies}
        autoHighlight
        getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => onChange(newValue)}
        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => {
          return option.title === value.title || option.title === input.value;
        }}
        renderInput={params => {
          return (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              {...rest}
              value={input.value}
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
            />
          );
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AutoHobbyComplete;
```

[image: Edit FORM VALUES]

Comment: The AutoHobbyComplete seems to work well but when I try to press next after entering multiple hobby, the fields get cleared and no values are through. Can you check this issue please?

Comment: Sure let me have a look and get back

Comment: Updated the demo. Was just a matter of removing {...rest} from TextField in MultipleComplete.js. The onBlur function in input params clears the data as the expectation is different there

Comment: cheers it works. If I try to go back or press next and then comeback to second page to change the first field (autohobbycomplete) I get a error saying value is undefined. if I write   if (value) {
                    return option.title === value.title || option.title === input.value;
                }  should it be fine?

Comment: can i just ask you one more thing? what if the array in autohobbyfield has multiple schema? right now it has only one called title (watching movie) but what if i was to add a description field? it only seems to take in title as the value not the whole object

Comment: You could do so via the onChange eventhandler in AutoComponent  like we do for MultiHobby component

Comment: on change is exactly the same as multihobby but it doesnt work for the AutoComponent part

Comment: Updated the demo for the change that you required

Answer (score 0):

It seems that youre correct, the value just isnt being displayed properly. If you are able to get the value from your redux form you can pass that value as an inputValue to the autocomplete. This will display the value in the text box. Make sure to use inputValue and not value.

```
 <Autocomplete
        inputValue={//this is where your redux form value should be displayed}
        autoSelect
        options={hobbies}
        autoHighlight
        getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => console.log(newValue)}
        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.title === value.title}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField {...params} {...input} value="test" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: i see how about the second field in the second page? i dont think any values are getting through for that one